# Amazon SNSを使用したpush通知をMonacaで行いたい

Tags: monaca, amazon-sns

Monacaアプリ初回起動時に、
デバイストークン、登録IDを取得し、
Amazon SNSにエンドポイントを作成し、
phpなどを使用し別のサーバーからpush依頼を投げ、
Monacaのアプリでpush通知を受信したい
のですが、情報がほとんど有りません。

NaitiveだとAWSからSDKが提供されていますので、出来ましたが、
Monacaで実装したいので、ご存知の方いらっしゃいましたらアドバイス下さい。

Cordvaプラグインを自作して行うのかなと思うのですが、なんとも。

Answer (score 1):

よく分かってないので間違ってるかもしれませんが
AWS SDK for JavaScript in the Browser は SNS に対応してるようですので使えませんか？

http://aws.typepad.com/aws_japan/2013/11/developer-preview-aws-sdk-for-javascript.html

Comment: ありがとうございます！調べます。分かり次第また結果ご報告します。

Answer (score 1):

[Amazon SNSとAdobe PhoneGap Buildを利用したプッシュ通知アプリの作成](https://www.infoscoop.org/blogjp/2014/08/22/amazon-sns-adobe-phonegap-build-push-notification/)

こちらの記事がほぼそのままの内容かなと思います。

PushPluginがdeprecatedになっているので、代わりに、

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push

このプラグインをMonacaにインストールし、あとは記事の通りに設定すればできそうな気がしますが...